# CreateService and quotes for lpBinaryPathName parameter

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, driver

I'm trying to install a kernel driver from an MFC application using [`CreateService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450(v=vs.85).aspx) function and I'm not sure that I fully understand how `lpBinaryPathName` parameter is supposed to be set up.

Quoting MSDN:

> The fully qualified path to the service binary file. If the path
>   contains a space, it must be quoted so that it is correctly
>   interpreted. For example, "d:\my share\myservice.exe" should be
>   specified as "\"d:\my share\myservice.exe\"".
>
> The path can also include arguments for an auto-start service. For
>   example, "d:\myshare\myservice.exe arg1 arg2". These arguments are
>   passed to the service entry point (typically the main function).

So I do this:

```
LPCTSTR pStrDriverFilePath;     //Driver full path
LPCTSTR pStrDriverFileParams;       //Parameters


hSCManager = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE);

CString strDrvPath;
strDrvPath.Format(L"\"%s\"", pStrDriverFilePath);

if(pStrDriverFileParams &&
    pStrDriverFileParams[0])
{
    strDrvPath.AppendFormat(L" %s", pStrDriverFileParams);
}

CreateService(hSCManager, pStrDriverName, pStrDriverDispName, 
    SERVICE_START | DELETE | SERVICE_STOP | SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS,
    dwDriverType, dwStartType, dwErrorCtrl,
    strDrvPath,
    NULL, NULL, NULL,
    NULL, NULL);
```

But then when I try to start it:

```
StartService(hScDrvHandle, 0, NULL);
```

it fails with the error code 123, or `ERROR_INVALID_NAME`:

> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

*Edit: This is how it ends up looking in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\` key:*

[image]

It only works if I remove double quotes (but only w/o a parameter.)

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code? What is the actual value of `strDrvPath` at the call to `CreateService()`?

Comment: I have tons of services installed on my machine that have spaces in their paths and thus are quoted in their `ImagePath`, just like yours. I have a few services that have BOTH a quoted path AND command-line parameters, and they start up just fine. Most of my services that use command-line parameters do not have paths with spaces in them, though. As an alternative, you might consider creating a `Parameters` subkey and put the `v=1` value in that key instead, and then update your service code to look for that parameter in the Registry instead of the command line.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes, I've done it myself with service paths too. Could it be something specific for a kernel driver though? Maybe it doesn't like that I placed the `.sys` file on the desktop in my test process?

Comment: you install kernel mode driver. it must not have " in path. even if it have space. and can not have command line. simply remove " from path

Comment: @RbMm: Oh, wow, it does make sense now since you said it. That's right, there's nowhere in `DriverEntry()` that it receives those command line parameters. So that sentence in MSDN is just for user-mode services only. Thank you for pointing it out! One last question though, while digging thru paths of other installed drivers I noticed that their paths begin with `%SystemRoot%`, but when I tried `%UserProfile%` in my case it wasn't recognized. Are there different env variables that exist for that path there that I can use and some that I cannot?

Comment: you can not use %UserProfile% because it depend from concrete user (token), while driver is global and loaded not in context of concrete user